# Is "$x$ is an $n$-tuple" $\Delta_0$?

Tags: set-theory

We follow Kuratowski's definition. Since $f(x, y) = (x, y)$ is rudimentary, we know that for all integer $n$ in the metalaungage, "$x$ is an $n$-tuple" is $\Delta_0$. But how about for $n$ inside the language? My attempt is like this:

$$x \text{ is an } n \text{-tuple} \iff n \in \omega \land \exists y[y \text{ is a function} \land \operatorname{dom}
(y) = n \land x = y(n - 1) \land (\forall i \in n)[i \ne 0 \implies y(i) \text{ is an ordered pair} \land \pi_2(y(i)) = y(i - 1)]]$$

The problem rises from the quantifier $\exists y$. And in similar fashion we can define projections for $n$ inside the language like this:

$$\pi_n(x) = y \iff n \in \omega \land \exists z[z \text{ is a function} \land \operatorname{dom}
(z) = n \land y = \pi_1(z(n - 1)) \land (\forall i \in n - 1)[z(i + 1) = \pi_2(z(i))]] $$

The reason why I try to formalize the notion of tuple is because of this: Let $(M, \in)$ be a set-sized model and $\vDash_M$ be the satisfaction relation. For any formula $\phi$ of the language of set theory formalized inside, let us call $\phi(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ a representation of $\phi$ when all free variables of $\phi$ is among $x_1, \ldots, x_n$.

Then I want to construct a function $D_{\phi(x_1, \ldots, x_n)} = \{(y_1, \ldots y_n) \in M^n \mid \vDash_M \phi(y_1, \ldots, y_n)\}$ defined for all representations. To define such a function, we should be able to handle tuples of varying length, projection to varying index, and substitution repeated varying times. So the question whether they are $\Delta_0$ came up to my mind.

By the way there is an option abandoning $n$-tuples and just using $n$-sequences, but I am working with Gödel operations and rudimentary functions so I would like to use $n$-tuples.

Comment: To clarify, you're defining tuples by iterating Kuratowski's definition of ordered pairs?

Comment: @Reveillark yes thats right and 1-tuples are just sets.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this is what you want, do let me know!

We induct on $n\in\omega$. To spell out the logical niceties, we will prove that, for every $n\in\omega$, $n>0$, there is a $\Delta_0$ (formal) formula $\phi_n$ such that, if $M$ is a transitive set, then 
$$
(M,\in )\models \phi_n(x) \iff \Phi(n,x)
$$
where $\Phi(u,v)$ is a formula in the LST which asserts that $u$ is a natural number and $v$ is a $u$-tuple.

For $n=1$, take $\phi_1(v):=(v\dot{=}v)$ (here, $\dot{=}$ is a symbol for equality).

For $n=2$, take $\phi_2(v)$ to be
$$
\exists u \in v \exists w\in u \exists z\in u [v=\langle w,z\rangle]
$$
where $x=\langle w,z\rangle$ abbreviates a $\Delta_0$ formula which says the obvious thing. 
Let $\phi_n$ witness the inductive hypothesis. Then we can let $\phi_{n+1}(v)$ be the formula
$$
\exists u\in v\exists w\in u\exists z\in u [\phi_n(w)\wedge v=\langle w,z\rangle]
$$
Since $\phi_n$ is $\Delta_0$, so is $\phi_{n+1}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. By the way what you've defined is perfectly $\Delta_0$ but the $n$ below $\phi$ is actually outside $M$, which is analogous to the "integer in the metalanguage" for $V$, so that we can't do something inside in $M$ like $\exists n \phi_n(x)$. So my question is: Can $\Phi$ be actually $\Delta_0$?

Comment: @Ris Ah, I see what you're asking now, my apologies! As you note in your question, $\Phi$ is arising recursively, which usually makes the complexity jump from $\Delta_0$ to $\Delta_1$ due to the function quantifier. I'd put my money on $\Phi$ "being" $\Delta_1$ (more precisely, equivalent to both $\Sigma_1$ and $\Pi_1$ formulas), which obviously buys you all the absoluteness you could ever want, but I don't know how we would actually go about proving it is *not* equivalent to a $\Delta_0$ formula.

Comment: I think we can do like this: Let $T$ be a sufficient subtheory of $\mathsf{ZF}$ such that we can prove that $\Phi$ is $\Delta_1$. Then take a transitive model satisfying a theory weaker than $T$(Because with $T$ it should be absolute) and showing that It wasn't actually absolute!